# Using PixelCopy to copy a scaled View within a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-view, android-pixel-copy

I have a `DialogFragment` that creates an `AlertDialog` with a custom view in `onCreateDialog`. The custom view includes a spinning progress bar and a prompt as well as a large view (larger than screen dimensions) that is fit inside the custom content via `scaleX` and `scaleY` values.

I am using the `PixelCopy` API to copy only the large view into a bitmap. This works well, but with a rather annoying caveat:

I call `PixelCopy` as such:

```
val winloc = intArrayOf(0, 0)
view.getLocationOnScreen(winloc)

val offset = 0
val left = winloc[0] + offset
val top = winloc[1] + offset
val rect = Rect(left, top, left + view.measuredWidth, top + view.measuredHeight)
PixelCopy.request(getDialog().getWindow(), rect, bitmap, listener, view.handler)
```

The `view.getLocationOnScreen(winloc)` returns x and y coordinates of `(84, 84)`

When I check the generated bitmap, `PixelCopy` has captured a whole lot of frame, padding, shadows, and the actual view content (with a bit missing from bottom right). The part of the actual content that is missing is exactly the same amount as the frame, padding, and shadow that I get at the top left of the image.

Having tried anything else I could think of to get the *correct* bounds of this content I want to save, I started adding random values to the coordinates (the `offset` value above). On a *Nexus 6P* an offset of `112` was perfect. Now I can't just throw `112` in there without reason because 1. it's a magic number and 2. it only works on one device.

I have ran out of ideas as to how I can get the correct bounds for this view OR where I can find this `112` value so that I can properly offset what I have.

As the app is unreleased, I can't include actual screenshots, but here are some redacted screenshots (ignore the black bars).

Some notes about the screenshots:

- The green part comes from `dialog!!.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(0xff00ff00.toInt()))` so I could outline the window bounds. The transparent/shadow bit between the screen edges and the green rectangle ... is this a margin or padding?
- The white rectangle with the red (content 1) and the blue (content 2) rectangles is the portion going to the bitmap
- The red and the blue rectangles within the content are different views generated from the same data.
- The blue portion contains a few `SurfaceView`s that I suspect I'd have to extract separately.

Device screenshot
[image: device screenshot]

Captured Bitmap (without the `112` magic number offset)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution so far has been to ditch the `DialogFragment` and use a regular `Fragment`. After inspecting the layouts, there were two paddings of `56` pixels, without any accessors to get their values. I suspect there's a bug somewhere in the private decor views that doesn't account for these paddings when calculating the location of the view in window.
I'll mark this as the answer until a better answer comes along.