# Cardview Rounded Corners are not showing up in Screenshot?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-cardview, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying take screenshot of a cardview which is in a DialogFragment. When I take a screenshot via Code. Top rounded corners are not showing but the bottom rounded corners are showing correctly. I saw these issues mentioned in the below Questions...

[Cardview loses its radius when taken a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244119/cardview-loses-its-radius-when-taken-a-screenshot-programmatically)

[Using PixelCopy to copy a scaled View within a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550406/using-pixelcopy-to-copy-a-scaled-view-within-a-dialogfragment)

As per the above question, I tested the same layout & code in a Fragment class. Then the rounded corners are showing up correctly...

**LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainlinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_margin="18dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="28dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorCand"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/turtle" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/type"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_idea" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="RtlCompat"
                    tools:text="Sea Turtle Day" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                android:background="@color/colorGray">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tag"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/category_icon"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    tools:text="#SeaTurtleDay#SeaTurtleDay" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/category_icon"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/animals" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wwf_logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ShotDialog.java**

```
public class ShotDialog extends DialogFragment {

    StkyrDialogBinding mBind;
    private static Context mCon;
    private static Boolean viaEntity;
    private String mLink;

    public ShotDialog() {
    }

    public static ShotDialognewInstance(Context context, Stkyr mStk, Boolean entityOnclick) {
        StkyrDialog frag = new StkyrDialog();
        mCon = context;
        viaEntity = entityOnclick;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("STK", mStk);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBind = ShotDialogBinding.inflate(inflater);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            mBind.fwd.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) mCon).getSupportFragmentManager();
                BottomDialogFragment mBot = BottomDialogFragment.newInstance(mCon, mBind.mainlinear);
                mBot.show(fm, "ShareDialog");
            });

        }

        return mBind.getRoot();
    }

}
```

**BottomDialogFragment.java** (From this Bottomsheet the screenshot code is triggered for the above Dialog)

```
public class BottomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public static Context mCon;
    private static View stkView;

    DialogShareBinding mBind;
    private String sharePath = "no";

    public static BottomDialogFragment newInstance(Context context, View view) {
        mCon = context;
        stkView = view;
        return new BottomDialogFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mBind = DialogShareBinding.inflate(inflater);
        return mBind.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mBind.stkShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        mBind.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
                Log.e("onClick: ", "SS TRIGGER");
                takeStkShot();
            }
        });
    }


    public void takeStkShot() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            ViewImage.Companion.getScreenShotFromView(stkView, getActivity(), (bm) -> {
                Log.e("takeStkShot: ", "> > >");
                storeImage(bm);
                return null;
            });
        } else {
            Bitmap bm = ViewImage.Companion.getScreenShot(stkView);
            storeImage(bm);
            Log.e("takeStkShot: ", "> > > ScreenShot");
        }
    }

    private void storeImage(Bitmap bm) {
        Log.e("takeScreenshot: ", "STORING");
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", now);
        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpeg";

            try {
                Log.d("ShareImageCreate", bm.toString());
                File imageFile = new File(mPath);

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                int quality = 100;
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                //setting screenshot in imageview
                String filePath = imageFile.getPath();

                Log.e("takeScreenshot > > ", filePath);

                Bitmap ssbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //iv.setImageBitmap(ssbitmap);
                sharePath = filePath;
                Log.d("ShareImageCreate", sharePath);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SCREENSHOT STORED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**ShotFragment.java** (This Gives expected result with rounded corners)

```
public class ShotFragment extends Fragment {

    String mEntityType = Constants.CAUSE;
    Bundle mBundle;
    ExtendedFloatingActionButton nextFab;
    AppCompatImageView img;
    CardView mCard;

    private String sharePath = "no";


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_test, container, false);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create Screenshot");

        mCard = root.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        mCard.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        takeStkShot();
        return root;
    }

    public void takeStkShot() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            ViewImage.Companion.getScreenShotFromView(mCard, getActivity(), (bm) -> {
                Log.e("takeStkShot: ", "> > >");
                storeImage(bm);
                return null;
            });
        } else {
            Bitmap bm = ViewImage.Companion.getScreenShot(mCard);
            storeImage(bm);
            Log.e("takeStkShot: ", "> > > ScreenShot");
        }
    }

    private void storeImage(Bitmap bm) {
        Log.e("takeScreenshot: ", "STORING");
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", now);
        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpeg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            //View v1 = lyTakeScreenShots.getRootView();

            try {
                Log.d("ShareImageCreate", bm.toString());
                File imageFile = new File(mPath);

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                int quality = 100;
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                //setting screenshot in imageview
                String filePath = imageFile.getPath();

                Log.e("takeScreenshot > > ", filePath);

                Bitmap ssbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //iv.setImageBitmap(ssbitmap);
                sharePath = filePath;
                Log.d("ShareImageCreate", sharePath);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SCREENSHOT STORED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The dialog is in its own window. Not sure if that is related to the problem or not, but you may want to take a look at how a view's window plays into taking a screen shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following as a replacement for *ViewImage.kt* in the referenced project. The main change is to pass in the view's window rather than an *Activity*. Dialogs have their own windows and don't share a window with activities.

**ViewImage.kt**

```
/**
 * Bulk of code borrowed from "Taking Screenshot Programmatically Using PixelCopy Api"
 * by Shivesh Karan Mehta
 * https://medium.com/@shiveshmehta09/taking-screenshot-programmatically-using-pixelcopy-api-83c84643b02a
 */

class ViewImage {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getScreenShotFromView(view: View, window: Window, callback: (Bitmap) -> Unit) {
            val bitmap: Bitmap
            // PixelCopy is available since API 24 but doesn't seem to work 100% until API 29.
            // The build version statement can be adjusted according to how well PixelCopy
            // works in your environment before "P".
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                val locationOfView = IntArray(2)
                view.getLocationInWindow(locationOfView)
                val rect = Rect(locationOfView[0], locationOfView[1],
                        locationOfView[0] + view.width, locationOfView[1] + view.height)

                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                try {
                    PixelCopy.request(window, rect, bitmap,
                            { copyResult: Int ->
                                if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                                    callback(bitmap)
                                }
                                // possible to handle other result codes ...
                            },
                            Handler()
                    )
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    // PixelCopy may throw IllegalArgumentException, make sure to handle it
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            } else {
                bitmap = getScreenShot(view)
                callback(bitmap)
            }
        }

        //      Method which will return Bitmap after taking screenshot. We have to pass the view which
//      we want to take screenshot.
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        @JvmStatic
        fun getScreenShot(view: View): Bitmap {
            view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.drawingCache)
            view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
            return bitmap
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we support this below API 26 ?

Comment: @user3467240 The updated code should work <API 26. I ran across an issue with _PixelCopy_ reducing the size of the image on API 28 and before but it may work for you on those versions. I don't know what the issue is. The drawing cache is the fall back.

Comment: @user3467240 There is a small project [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Cheticamp/TakeScreenshot2) that demonstrates the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I Noticed that you are trying to take a screenshot from 'mainRelative' which does not exist in your xml, I think you should use the id of 'cardView' or 'mainlinear' based on your requirements.

Comment: sorry it was just a typo error. I have fixed it....

Answer (score 0):

*The Answer given by @Cheticamp is right
Lets Convert it into java*

```
public class ScreenshotTaker {

    private static final String TAG = ScreenshotTaker.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Takes screenshot of given view and saves it in external storage
     * @param view outer most ViewGroup that you want a screenshot of
     * @return File object of saved screenshot in storage
     */
    public static File captureScreenshot(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return saveBitmap(view.getContext(),bitmap);
    }

    public interface screenshotFile{
        void onComplete(File file);
    }

    public static void getScreenShotFromView(View view, Window window, screenshotFile callback ) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        // PixelCopy is available since API 24 but doesn't seem to work 100% until API 29.
        // The build version statement can be adjusted according to how well PixelCopy
        // works in your environment before "P".
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            int[] locationOfView = new int[2];
            view.getLocationInWindow(locationOfView);
            Rect rect = new Rect(locationOfView[0], locationOfView[1],
                    locationOfView[0] + view.getWidth(), locationOfView[1] + view.getHeight());

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            try {
                PixelCopy.request(window, rect, bitmap, new PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPixelCopyFinished(int copyResult) {
                        if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {

                            callback.onComplete(saveBitmap(view.getContext(),bitmap));
                        }
                    }
                }, new Handler()
                );
            }catch (Exception ignored){ }
        }
    }

}
```